# Как изменить отсчет системы координат ImageBox

Tags: c#

Изменить с левого верхнего угла на центр ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Какие координаты вы имеете в виду?

Comment: По-умолчанию отсчет в системе координат ведется сверху вниз (Y) и слева направо (X). Мне нужно систему координат центрировать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.TranslateTransform((float)imageBox.Width / 2, (float)imageBox.Height / 2);
```

Кстати, вы, вероятно, ошибаетесь - в WinForms (если речь идет о нем) нет ImageBox, но есть PictureBox

Comment: Да, это то что нужно. Как теперь ещё ось Y повернуть вверх ?

Comment: юзайте RotateTransform


И вообще очень настоятельно рекомендую почитать про аффыинные преобразования - это азы работы с графикой

Comment: понятно, спасибо